# Nginx force redirect or rewrite mp3 url path

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have this mp3 url:

`http://example.com/downloads/low_quality/songs/song_name.mp3`

and i want force rewrite to this url without allow downloading first url:

`http://example.com/downloads/high_quality/songs/song_name.mp3`

Indeed i need replace `low_quality` with `high_quality` path. I trying use `alias` and `rewrite`, but not working. it start downloading first url `low_quality`.

```
location /downloads/low_quality/ {
    alias /downloads/high_quality/;
}
```

or

```
location ~* ^/downloads/low_quality/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/downloads/low_quality/(.*)$ http://example.com/downloads/high_quality/$1 permanent; 
    break;
}
// but low quality download started!
```

`low_quality` file always is exists but i don't want downloading when requested. i want redirect(rewrite) to second url `high_quality`.

Comment: @RichardSmith `server_name` and `root` server is same. i cannot create separate block!

Comment: @RichardSmith no need logs and details. i want just prevent downloding when rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

this is true rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/downloads/low_quality/songs/(\w+)\.?.*$ /downloads/high_quality/songs/$1.mp3 last;
```

high quality requested and downloaded.